# Match data in row and copy

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am stuck. I have corresponding data on two sheets. I want to go down the rows in sheet1, use the value in column M, find the matching value in sheet3 column M, then copy the data into sheet1. Sheet1 is 4000 lines. My copy logic is working, unfortunately, my loop does not end and it copies row1 until excel freezes. Any assistance is greatly appreciated - obviously I am still a VBA novice.

```
Dim searchTerm As String
Dim r As Long
  For i = 1 To 4000

  
      searchTerm = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M" & i).Text
      If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M" & i).Value = searchTerm Then


         'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
         Worksheets("Sheet3").Select
         Range("A" & i & startcolumn & ":AU" & i & lastcolumn).Select
         Selection.Copy
         

         'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
         Sheets("Sheet1").Select
         Columns("AX").Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

         'Move counter to next row
        

         'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
         Sheets("Sheet1").Select

      End If
Next i
```

Comment: Your `if`-statement always is true.

Answer (score 0):

### A VBA Lookup

- The following will loop through each cell in range "M1:M4000" of worksheet "Sheet1" and try to find each cell's value in column "M" of "Sheet3". If found, the values from columns "A" to column "AU" in the found row of worksheet "Sheet3" will be copied to worksheet "Sheet1", to the same sized row range starting with column "AX".

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SimpleLookup()

    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Destination
    
    ' Define Destination Worksheet.
    Dim dst As Worksheet
    Set dst = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim lValue As Variant ' Lookup Value
    Dim i As Long         ' Destination Rows Counter
    
    ' Source
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet.
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Set src = wb.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    ' Define Copy Range.
    Dim cRng As Range
    Set cRng = src.Range("A1:AU4000")
    ' Define Lookup Column Range.
    Dim lRng As Range
    Set lRng = cRng.Columns(13)
    
    Dim rRng As Range     ' Current Copy Row Range
    Dim lIndex As Variant ' Lookup Index
    
    ' Loop
    
    ' Loop through rows (cells) of Criteria Column Range.
    For i = 1 To 4000
        ' Write the value of the current cell to a variable, Lookup Value.
        lValue = dst.Cells(i, "M").Value
        ' Define Lookup Index, the index (row) where the Lookup value
        ' was found in Lookup Column Range.
        lIndex = Application.Match(lValue, lRng, 0)
        ' Evaluate Lookup Index: it will be an error value if not found.
        If Not IsError(lIndex) Then
            ' Define Current Copy Row Range.
            Set rRng = cRng.Rows(lIndex)
            ' Either...:
            ' Values only.
            ' Copy Current Copy Row Range to Destination Worksheet.
            dst.Cells(i, "AX").Resize(, rRng.Columns.Count).Value = rRng.Value
            ' ...Or:
            ' Values, formulas, formats.
            'rRng.Copy Destionation:=dst.Cells(i, "AX")
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```